# Align the latex output of sympy?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

The display of LaTeX equations in sympy appear as an unbroken line:

`a = b + c + d(e - fg) + hij`

I would like this to appear as something like

```
a = b
  + c 
  + d(e 
      -
      fg) 
  + hij
```

or perhaps customizing how long the line can be before wrapping and aligning, like for example:

```
a = b + c 
  + d(e - fg) 
  + hij
```

Is such a thing possible?